# "First I bring you Christmas greetings; afterwards I give you beatings!"

Tags: dc, superman, episode-identification

My dad remembers these immortal words being spoken by Bizarro in a Superman comic book from the 1960s, probably between 1962 and 1967. Bizarro Superman was saying it to his Bizarro family, probably while wearing a Santa hat or even a Santa suit.

It may have been a comic published around Christmas, but with Bizarro you never know. As Dad points out, "Bizarro Christmas is probably the fourth of July."

Can anyone point us toward the issue in which this took place?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like the *Tales of the Bizarro World* segment printed in *Adventure Comics* #290 in November 1961. The Christmas bit was only a few panels, but they were all the same brand of delightful absurdity you'd expect from Silver Age Superman. The phrase wasn't actually *spoken* by Bizarro, but written on a Christmas card:

[image]

**Transcript:**

> Christmas cheer
>   Now am hear.
>   Excoose me while
>   Me skratch my ear.
>   Me want giv yu
>   Seasun's Greetings,
>   Afterwurd, me giv yu
>   Beatings!!!

Bizarro-Claus (Bizarro #1 in a Santa costume) also makes an appearance:

[image]

Comment: I stand by my earlier comment that there is no plotline so vastly stupid that it hasn't been found in a Superman comic at some point.

Comment: @Richard Well, it was the 60s

Comment: As if that's an excuse for anything. Bizarro Superman is the dumbest idea ever, aside from all the other dumb ideas.

Comment: Heck and dang, that was bizarrely fast! Thanks so much, from my dad and me, and Merry Christmas!

Comment: @RyanVeeder An Unmerry Christmas to you and yours, from Bizarro-SFF